# How to set/get selected text in sap.m.select?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I only find `setSelectedItem` `setSelectedItemId`  `setSelectedKey`  in [sap.m.select doc](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Select.html), how to setSelected text in `sap.m.select`?

For example:

```
            <Select
                forceSelection="false"
                selectedKey="{/ProductCollection/0/ProductId}"
                items="{
                    path: '/ProductCollection',
                    sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                }">
                <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
            </Select>`
```

How to get selected text (Name) in this control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys shall be unique but the texts do not have to be unique. In some situations the texts are translated but the keys stay the same. Thats why the keys are used for selection.

To get the text of the selected item you can use

```
var text = select.getSelectedItem().getText();
```

To select an item by text you have to search the model for the item,  get its key and use that with `setSelectedKey()`.